# Why does the image of this parameterization appear disconnected?

Tags: plotting

Why the image of this parameterization appears disconnected. Thanks.

```
  X=6Cos[u](1+Sin[u])+4(1-Cos[u]/2)Cos[u]Cos[v];
  Y=16Sin[u]+4(1-Cos[u]/2)Sin[u]Cos[v];
  Z=4(1-Cos[u]/2)Sin[v];
  p1=ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X,Y,Z}],{u,0,Pi},{v,0,2Pi},Axes->False,Boxed->False]
```

[image]

```
X=6Cos[u](1+Sin[u])+4(1-Cos[u]/2)Cos[v+Pi];
Y=16Sin[u];
Z=4(1-Cos[u]/2)Sin[v];
p2=ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X,Y,Z}],{u,Pi,2Pi},{v,0,2Pi},Axes->False,Boxed->False]
```

[image]

```
Row[{p1,p2}]

bx=6Cos[u](1+Sin[u]); by = 16 Sin[u]; r=4(1-Cos[u]/2); 
X=If[Pi<u<=2Pi,bx+r Cos[v+Pi],bx+r Cos[u]Cos[v]];
Y=If[Pi<u<=2Pi, by, by+r Sin[u]Cos[v]];
Z=r Sin[v];
p= ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X,Y,Z}],{u,0,2Pi},{v,0,2Pi},PlotPoints->32,Axes->False,Boxed->False,ViewPoint->{1.4,-2.6,-1.7}]
```

[image]

```
Show[p,ViewPoint->{1,0,1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the output of `$Version`. I don't see this on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: MMA version 13.2 I do not see this either.

Comment: 13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2022)

Comment: But I'm using Mathematica App on Ipad Air 5, something called 'Wolfram Cloud'.

Comment: Well, if you say you don't see it in computer, then the question is solved. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't about the parameterization. It's curious, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

With my system, your code produces the gap.

```
bx = 6 Cos[u] (1 + Sin[u]); by = 16 Sin[u]; r = 4 (1 - Cos[u]/2);
X = If[Pi < u <= 2 Pi, bx + r Cos[v + Pi], bx + r Cos[u] Cos[v]];
Y = If[Pi < u <= 2 Pi, by, by + r Sin[u] Cos[v]];
Z = r Sin[v];
p = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X, Y, Z}], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> 32, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The issue arises from the `Automatic` setting for `Exclusions`

```
Options[ParametricPlot3D, Exclusions]

(* {Exclusions -> Automatic} *)
```

To eliminate the gap, preclude any `Exclusions`

```
p4 = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{X, Y, Z}], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> 32, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, 0, 1}, 
  Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]